# Magento 2 : Custom phtml file for custom shipping method

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, magento-enterprise-2

I am able to add a custom shipping method and I want to add a custom template for that shipping method. I have followed [this article](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-shipping-module-magento-2/) to create a custom shipping method.  Is there any way to add custom phtml file for custom shipping method?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edited :**

Following is my approach. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

> app/code/Custom/Shipping/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step-custom" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="step-config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-rates-validation before-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="fedex-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Custom_Shipping/js/view/customshipping</item>                                                                    
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Custom/Shipping/view/frontend/web/js/view/customshipping.js

```
define([
        'uiComponent'
    ],
    function (
        Component
    ) {
        "use strict";
        console.log('zed blackbeard');
        return Component.extend({
          initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            console.log('inside initialize function')
          },
          defaults: {
            template: 'Custom_Shipping/customshipping',
          },
        })
    }
);
```

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot, js called but the template is not rendering.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try something like this :
```

create yours custom block, create your xml (path of reference route you can check in xml of shipping methods), create phtml.

Go to app\design\frontend\Themes\Yourtheme\layout\extension.xml

Create block
The Block file should contain all the view logic required, it should not contain any kind of html or css. Block file are supposed to have all application view logic.

Create a file:

```
app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Block/Display.php
```

Contents would be:

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block;
class Display extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function sayHello()
    {
        return __('Hello World');
    }
}
```

Every block in Magento 2 must extend from `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`. In this block we will define a method `sayHello()` to show the word “Hello World”. We will use it in template file.

Create template file
Create a template file call sayhello.phtml

```
app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/sayhello.phtml
```

Insert the following code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @var \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Display $block
 */

echo $block->sayHello();
```

In the layout file, we define the template by `Mageplaza_HelloWorld::sayhello.phtml`. It mean that Magento will find the file name `sayhello.phtml` in templates folder of module Mageplaza_HelloWorld. The template folder of the module is `app/code/{vendor_name}/{module_name}/view/frontend/templates/`

see base tutorial, how to use xml,block,controller here :

```
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html
```